Performing renormalization on the interaction constant $g$ to prevent UV divergence in BEC system
I am applying perturbation theory method for the Hemiltonian of a specific BEC with interactions, where initially all the atoms are in the ground state $|g\rangle$. After few calculations at the second order in perturbation theory, I have to solve the integral
$$\epsilon^{(2)}=N^2 \frac{g^2}{4V^2} \frac{mV}{\hbar^2} \int_0^{infinity}d^3k/(2\pi)^3 1/k^2 $$
where $g$ is the interaction constant, $k$ are the momentums of the particles, $N$ is the number of particles and $V$ is the volume. This integral diverges (UV divergence) and the origin of this divergence is due to the hypothesis that he interaction potential is defined as $V = g*\delta(r)$. To solve this integral for $\epsilon^{(2)}$ I want to limit the integral between $0$ and the upper bound for k = $\Lambda$, and apply the renormalization on the $g$, so I define $g_{ren}$ as $$1/g = 1/g_{ren} - \frac{mV\Lambda}{2\pi^2\hbar^2}.$$
Evaluating the integral between $k = 0 $ and $k = \Lambda$ and then substituting the new definition of $g$ in the expression for $\epsilon^{2}$, I so get the result
$$\epsilon^{(2)} = \frac{N^2}{4V^2}(\frac{g_{ren}}{1-\frac{g_{ren}mV\Lambda}{2\pi^2\hbar^2}})^2 \frac{mV\Lambda}{2\pi^2\hbar^2}.$$
My question is, why it seems to me that this solution still diverges? Did I apply well the renormalization?

Renormalization involves four sets of scales:

cutoff scales, e.g. $\Lambda$ (and/or $\mu$ for IR divergent theories, and possibly other cutoff scales in condensed matter systems with special symmetries), which you need to show don't strongly impact calculations,
coupling scales, e.g. $\lambda_0 = \gamma \lambda_r$, which are chosen for convenience,
field scales, e.g. $\phi_0 = Z\phi_r$, also chosen for convenience,
coordinate scales, e.g. $x_0 = \alpha x_r$, also chosen for convenience.

The idea is that by choosing $\gamma$, $Z$, and $\alpha$ so that order-by-order calculations are consistent (i.e. some complete set of physical characteristics or quantities, such as transition amplitudes or poles in the propagator, are "asserted"/required to be the same in each order), you can take $\Lambda$ to infinity or $\mu$ to zero (adjusting $\gamma$, $Z$, $\alpha$, and $\lambda$ appropriately) while maintaining finite predictions.  It's sort of like how you need to rescale quantities defined in terms of a random walk to get analogous quantities for Brownian motion in the continuum limit (except local field theories in $d>1$ span a much larger set of universality classes than $d=1$, and so there are relatively few 'nice' concise descriptions of the continuum limit outside of, say, conformal field theories in $d=2$.) In your example, you are rescaling/modifying $g$ the coupling constant, but ignoring the field normalization $Z$ (and in more elaborate examples, the length scale normalization $\alpha$), which can also be defined/renormalized depending on $\Lambda$ and the order of perturbation theory so that your result (a two point function?) is finite.

OP needs to give a lot more context when asking question.  It would be helpful for anyone who attempts to answer the question, and ultimately help to get it answered.  I believe your $\epsilon^{(2)}$ is one-loop Feynman diagram to the 4-point vertex (two-body interaction), but don't expect everyone to decipher that.
And no, $\epsilon^{(2)}$ alone is not supposed to be finite.  I guess you have a first order $\epsilon^{(1)} \sim g \, (N/V)^2 $, omitting all the factors.  Your procedure is supposed to yields
$$
\epsilon^{(1)} + \epsilon^{(2)} \sim g_{ren} (N/V)^2 + O(g_{ren}^3).
$$
That is, the total interaction energy is finite up second order.  Beyond that, the sum $\epsilon^{(1)} + \epsilon^{(2)}$ is still divergent.  But that is beyond the order of this approximation.
In fact your $g_{ren}$ does a bit more than that.  You can go and calculate all the $\epsilon^{(n)}$ for arbitrary $n$, and it will turn out that
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \epsilon^{(n)} = g_{ren} (N/V)^2.
$$
This is why $g_{ren}$ was defined that way in the first place.
